# Building dynamic year/month headers for a grid

Tags: excel, date, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and have a requirement that will display 2 rows of headers where row 1 will show the year and row 2 will show the month.  This is across a 24 month period and will be driven by another date somewhere else in the data.  The 24 month period will start from the month of the date that drives these dynamic headers.  For ease of display the months will only show the 1st letter and the year will be merged and centred for each relevant year period.

For example, today's date would generate: -

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEURr.png)

As a test, assuming a date is entered in A1, I created this short code which does work, but It takes apporx 10 secs to generate the required headers and I don't understand why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim rngDate As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim rngYearStart As Range
    Dim rngYearEnd As Range
    Dim bytNumMonths As Byte
    Dim d As Date

    'Set inital ranges and columns
    Set rngDate = Range("A1")
    Set c = Range("C2")
    Set rngYearStart = c.Offset(-1, 0)
    bytNumMonths = 24

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngDate) Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            'Turn off screen refresh and alerts
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .EnableEvents = False

            'Unmerge current year headings
            'Force width if month heading columns.  Must be able to show yyyy
            Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & c.Offset(-1, bytNumMonths - 1).Address).UnMerge
            Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & c.Offset(-1, bytNumMonths - 1).Address).ColumnWidth = 4

            'Loop through number of columns and set values
            For i = 0 To bytNumMonths - 1
                d = DateAdd("m", i, rngDate)

                If Month(d) = 12 Then
                    Set rngYearEnd = c.Offset(-1, i)

                    rngYearStart.Value = Year(d)
                    Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & rngYearEnd.Address).Merge
                    Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & rngYearEnd.Address).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End If
                If Month(d) = 1 Then
                    Set rngYearStart = c.Offset(-1, i)
                End If
                c.Offset(0, i).Value = d
                c.Offset(0, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                c.Offset(0, i).NumberFormat = "mmmmm"
            Next

            'Set values for last column after loop
            Set rngYearEnd = c.Offset(-1, bytNumMonths - 1)

            rngYearStart = Year(d)
            Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & rngYearEnd.Address).Merge
            Range(rngYearStart.Address & ":" & rngYearEnd.Address).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If

ExitHandler:
    'Turn on screen refresh and alerts
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "There was an error." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "ERROR: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

As you can see it is pretty simple, looping through the months and assigning values to the relevant cells.

Can someone please have a look at this code and let me know if I'm doing it correctly and/or the most efficient way.  As I said, it does work, but is slow which I don't get.  Note, I have made sure that this code is running in a new workbook with nothing else that may slow it down.  Is it he best way to this?

Comment: Tested here with excel 2016 and it gets done almost instantly

Comment: Instantaneous here too, Excel 2013.

Comment: @cyberpunk Okay thanks.  So there's nothing wrong with the code? Should it be cleaned up in any way regardless? Any suggestions on what might be making it go slow? I'm running this on a fast Citrix network win Win7 x64 Excel 2010 32bit as the image. I could kinda see performance issues if the network is busy, but right now I'm one of the last people in the office. When I step through it, no line stands out as processing much slower than any other, The 2 lines that are assigning values to cells are fractionally slower, but it is a mere blip.  I don't get it. It's doing my head in.

Comment: @Vegard Okay thanks. So there's nothing wrong with the code? Should it be cleaned up in any way regardless? Any suggestions on what might be making it go slow? I'm running this on a fast Citrix network win Win7 x64 Excel 2010 32bit as the image. I could kinda see performance issues if the network is busy, but right now I'm one of the last people in the office. When I step through it, no line stands out as processing much slower than any other, The 2 lines that are assigning values to cells are fractionally slower, but it is a mere blip. I don't get it. It's doing my head in

Comment: Nothing that I can see, sorry. There are some structural things that look a little odd, such as most of your code being wrapped with `With Application`, but I don't think that is the cause of any lag (it worked fine for me, after all). Citrix overhead is a more likely culprit IMO.

Comment: @Vegard  Thanks.  Yea, the original code wrapped within `With Application` contained other things that hang off that object, but for this example I should have ended the With after turning off the alerts.  Forgetfulness.  I'll play around a bit more.  I can't do any local drive testing on this environment.